# Multiple Insert for each of the Account IDs?

Tags: sql-server

How do I effectively insert multiple rows without using loop for all of the Account-ID values?

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
(AccountID, ShowColumns, GroupColumns, AvgColumnsFlag)
VALUES
(1, 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3')
(1, 'abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3')
(1, 'xyz1', 'xyz1', 'xyz1')
```

In this case, I have over 20,000 account ids.  I can use one other table with unique account ID and do some kind of joining to get that.  Then use it to in place of the displayed example Account-ID of "1".

I don't know how you guys do with multiple inserts for each Account-ID.

Thanks...

**[Edit]**

I found a way to insert using data from other table recently but unfortunately I can only insert 1 row, not multiple rows.  :-(  See code below...  Is it possible to consolidate 3 of them into 1 instead?

```
 INSERT INTO tblDealerSavedDataMyInventorySavedBuilds
  (AccountId, LoadDefault, BuildName, ColumnShowAndSortOrderValues, ColumnGroupByValues, ColumnSortAverageValues)
  SELECT DISTINCT tblaAccounts.AccountID, 0, 'My Inventory by Count', 'ImportStatus|StockNumber|Vin|Year|Make ASC|Model ASC|Trim|Mileage|PurchasePrice|StockDate|RepairCost|TotalCost|DaysInInventory|InventoryTrackerLocation|Category', 'Make|Model', 'MyInventoryCount-SortOrderByCount'
  FROM tblaAccounts
  ORDER BY tblaAccounts.AccountID ASC

 INSERT INTO tblDealerSavedDataMyInventorySavedBuilds
  (AccountId, LoadDefault, BuildName, ColumnShowAndSortOrderValues, ColumnGroupByValues, ColumnSortAverageValues)
  SELECT DISTINCT tblaAccounts.AccountID, 0, 'My Inventory by Make', 'ImportStatus|StockNumber|Vin|Year|Make ASC|Model ASC|Trim|Mileage|PurchasePrice|StockDate|RepairCost|TotalCost|DaysInInventory|InventoryTrackerLocation|Category', 'Make|Model', 'MyInventoryCount-SortOrderByMake'
  FROM tblaAccounts
  ORDER BY tblaAccounts.AccountID ASC

 INSERT INTO tblDealerSavedDataMyInventorySavedBuilds
  (AccountId, LoadDefault, BuildName, ColumnShowAndSortOrderValues, ColumnGroupByValues, ColumnSortAverageValues)
  SELECT DISTINCT tblaAccounts.AccountID, 0, 'My Inventory by Purchase Price', 'ImportStatus|StockNumber|Vin|Year|Make ASC|Model ASC|Trim|Mileage|PurchasePrice|StockDate|RepairCost|TotalCost|DaysInInventory|InventoryTrackerLocation|Category', 'Make|Model', 'MyInventoryCount-SortOrderByCost'
  FROM tblaAccounts
  ORDER BY tblaAccounts.AccountID ASC
```

Comment: The question is not very clear, where is the data coming from? I think what you want is [Insert with Select](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records)

Comment: I think the solution for you would be `INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT .. ` .. but can you post some examples about how you mean to use the other table?

Comment: What table stores your 20,000 account IDs? And do you only want these three rows for each account ID, so 60,000 rows inserted total? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: See above of new sql scripts

Answer (score 0):

First insert into `@SourceTable` all your values.

Then use this statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT *
FROM @SourceTable
```

It may look the same, but it's different, **since you are actually addressing the table once**, instead of 20,000 times..

You can also do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT 1, 'foo1', 'foo2', 'f003'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'abc11', 'abc2', 'abc3'
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: Why would you even post the second option, if the first is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

To insert multiple rows with hard-coded values use

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
select 1, 'foo1', 'foo2', 'f003'
union all
select 2, 'abc11', 'abc2', 'abc3'
```

etc.

To insert from existing data

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3)
select srccol1, srccol22, srccol33 
from TableOrView
```